# Basic htaccess Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen dozens of others very similar questions but still can't figure it out...

I'm trying to make it so that people will see this URL in their browser :
http://mysite/blog-test/out-and-about/
But what actually loads is :
http://mysite/blog-test/?category=out-and-about

I'm a bit confused as to what rules I should use and in what order... Here's what I have so far in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  # Unrelated to the problem, I think ?
RewriteRule blog-test/(.+) blog-test/?category=$1 [L]
```

So far, it keeps giving me a 404 even though the /blog-test page exists.

I've checked, I have mod_rewrite enabled.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need lines two or three at all, so you can change it to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule blog-test/(.+) blog-test/?category=$1 [L]
```

And that should work fine, but clearly it doesn't from what you've already said. Are you sure that `.htaccess` files are being processed? You can check that by adding some garbage on a line and see if you get a 500 error.